# How do you say split in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, palabras-raras, solicitud-de-término

How would you say splits in general in Spanish? (See picture below)

[image]

I looked it up on word reference and found spagat.  Is that correct?

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(ejercicio_f%C3%ADsico)

Comment: I recently saw Kung Fu Panda and I'd swear the characters said "apertura lateral" to refer to that position. Though it is maybe called that way only in martial arts contexts, and not in general.

Answer (score 3):

Spagat is the technical name in *dance* argot, coming from the term in [German](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spagat). It is more commonly referred as "split"; which can be translated as 'estar abierto/a de piernas' - that is "to be with both legs open".

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. There really is no a single word to define that, but to use the same word "split", which is an anglicism. I have heard tons of dancers and ladies say they are practicing "splits" - just like that.

Comment: Spagat is German, not French

Answer (score -2):

Desgonzar is the correct term.

Comment: Can you expand on this so that we can see why you think this? Perhaps give some examples from online resources?

Comment: @mdewey I agree that as written, this is not much of an answer. It turns out that there are two verbs, [*desgonzar*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/desgonzar) and *desgoznar*, which differ only in having two letters transposed as if by [metátesis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Met%C3%A1tesis). They respectively derive from *gonce* and *gozne*, in which this transposition first occurred. Note that this is all about “hinges” (*goznes*) rather than about something more “scissors” (*tijeras*). Whether this is more appropriate than *split* in Spanish is a lengthier matter to investigate.

Comment: [Desgonzar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D1hua94): _Desencajar, desquiciar, Caer sin fuerzas por debilitamiento o cansancio físico_ does not seem to be the correct answer. You should explain **why** you think something is the correct answer when you post, including explanations, references, linkes, examples of how to ue it, etc. See [answer]. This is not only an incorrect answer, but a low quality one, since you are not explaining anything. Could you please improve your answer?